# Having trouble transforming tensor created by tf.fromPixels()

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

What I'm trying to do is convert a tensor which was created using `tf.fromPixels()` and transform that into `[28, 28]` to then use as that as an input to get a prediction from a model trained in Python.

What I'm having trouble with is the first layer in the model which takes an input shape of `[28, 28]`. When I create a tensor in NodeJS using `tf.fromPixels()` I get a tensor with a shape of `[28, 28, 1]` however, when I input that into the model prediction function I get an error message from the first flatten layer of the model.

> Error when checking : expected flatten_input to have shape [null, 28, 28] but got array with shape [28, 28, 1]

Before I go on here's the code I have for this part.

```
  prediction: async function(image) {
     const model = await tf.loadModel("file://models/model.json");

    const canvas = createCanvas(28, 28);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    loadImage(image).then(function(image) {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 28, 28);

        var image = tf.fromPixels(canvas, 1);
        var prediction = model.predict(image);

        return prediction;
     });
   }
```

I have tried reshaping the tensor to `[28, 28]` and trying `[null, 28, 28]`, however as you can probably imagine I get an error when using null. So what my question is how do I reshape the tensor to the correct shape?

Comment: You need to reshape your vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting your image from your canvas, you need to reshape your tensor

```
 var image = tf.fromPixels(canvas, 1);
 image = img.reshape([1, 28, 28]);
```

then you can pass the tensor to your model

Comment: Interesting. When I do that I get `Error when checking : expected flatten_input to have 3 dimension(s) but got array with shape [28, 28]`

Comment: Then it means that it should be a shape of [28, 28, 1] instead

Comment: That brings me back at the beginning getting `Error when checking : expected flatten_input to have shape [null, 28, 28] but got array with shape [28, 28, 1]`

Comment: Maybe, it should be [1, 28, 28] instead. If possible can you share your python model code ?